# ListBox that updates another part of View

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, listbox

I want a ListBox, that when submitted, will send its selected values to a controller, and the response from that controller will be used to update a small piece of the view.

The following code is able to update the part of the view, and get the selected values, but only separately. I cannot get the values from the ListBox while also updating a part of the page:

**Code that is able to return selected values to controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetInput(ListBoxModel mod)
{
    OtherModel data = new OtherModel();
    data.selected = mod;
    return View("HomePage", data);
}

@model App.Models.MainViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("GetInput", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <label for="optionList">Options:</label>
    @Html.ListBox("optionList", Model.listBoxMod.list)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

**This code is able to update part of the page, but can't get the data from the ListBox:**

```
public ActionResult GetInputAndUpdate(ListBoxModel mod)
{
    //get values out of mod and put them in NewList selectedValues
    //but no values appear in mod
    //I can put fake data in selectedValues and it will be put on the page
    return PartialView("PartialViewUpdate", selectedValues);
}
```

Main View:

```
@model App.Models.MainViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("GetInputAndUpdate", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <label for="CGSelected">Care Gaps:</label>
    @Html.ListBox("CGSelected", Model.listBoxMod.list)
    <input id="submitButton" data-url="@Url.Action("GetInputAndUpdate")" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <!-- <input id="loadFromMainFrame" data-url="@Url.Action("CareGapSubmitInit", Model ??? )" type="submit" value="Submit" /> This doesn't work! -->

//The partial view html gets put here
<div id="selectedValuesItem"></div>
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model App.Models.NewList
    @foreach(var str in Model)
    {
        @str
        <br />
    }
```

Code to update partial view:

```
$(function ()
{
    $("#submitButton").click(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).data("url");
        $("#selectedValuesItem").load(url);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from someone, and the correct way of doing this is the following:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("GetInput", "Home", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId = "selectedValuesItem"}))
{
    <label for="optionList">Care Gaps:</label>
    @Html.ListBox("optionList", Model.listBoxMod.list)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

And then include this script in the project like so:
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")

This will return the correct Model/selected items in the ListBox and the response view/html will be put in the selectedValuesItem div. It will also work multiselect boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call GetInputAndUpdate

```
$(function ()
{
    $("#submitButton").click(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = "@Url.Action("GetInputAndUpdate")?selectedValue=" + $("#optionList").val();
        $("#selectedValuesItem").load(url);
    });
```

This

```
public ActionResult GetInputAndUpdate(ListBoxModel mod)
```

becomes this

```
public ActionResult GetInputAndUpdate(string selectedValue)
```

Comment: How would this work for a multiselect box? And I found a simpler solution for the problem.